# VSCode Laravel Xdebug Error: Class "Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route" not found

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, xdebug

[image]

I installed Xdebug.

Xdebug **Launch currently open script**

> Error: Class "Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route" not found

Why is there an error?

Answer (score 0):

The VS Code plugin by default instructs Xdebug to set a break point on *all* Exceptions.

This is something that you can turn off in the lower left of your screen, by unticking `[ ] Everything` and `[ ] Exceptions` in the `Breakpoints` tab:

[image]

Comment: My question is not this.
Class "Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route" not found

The reason why there's an error when I shot the break point.

Comment: @codejay So which "currently opened script" are you trying to launch? If it's `web.php` (where that error is located) then the error is correct -- PHP (yes, PHP) is unable to locate that `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route` class since you are executing that file directly, bypassing the whole framework bootstrap logic.